# Kafka Cannot Configure Topics on Application Startup, but Later Can Communicate

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a spring boot application using spring-kafka (2.2.5.RELEASE) that always gets this error when starting up:

```
Could not configure topics 
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing 
topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

However, the application continues to startup:

```
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] 
INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions revoked: []
INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned: [my-reply-topic-1]
INFO  o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer - partitions assigned: [my-request-topic-0]
INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer -
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

At this point, the application interacts with Kafka as expected.

We like to keep our logs clean, so we would like to understand why this Exception is thrown. Also, it is a bit confusing, because when we move to a different environment where the networking has not been established between the application and the kafka broker(s), we get the same error, but the application does not function. Having the same Exception occur when there is truly a problem and when it can be ignored is irksome when trying to troubleshoot connectivity issues.

Is there a way, on application startup, to determine whether connectivity has been established with Kafka rather than just waiting for a timeout message (which may be a red herring anyway)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the topic(s) exist already, remove any `NewTopic` beans from the application context and the `KafkaAdmin` won't try to connect to the broker at all.

Comment: but what if app fail because of this even without `NewTopic` ?

Comment: That solves the problem. However if KafkaAdmin is configured correctly, it will find out itself, that the topic already exists and does nothing. If you see this timeout, most likely your KafkaAdmin cannot connect becaus it's not set-up correctly.